# What is the difference between SQLAlchemy Core and ORM?

Tags: sqlalchemy

What is the difference of purpose between [SQLAlchemy Core](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/) and [SQLAlchemy ORM](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/)?

Answer (score 44):

The ORM is, as the name implies, an *object-relational mapper*: Its purpose is to represent database relations as Python objects.

The core is a *query builder*. Its purpose is to provide a programmatic means to generate SQL queries (and DDL) -- but the results of those queries are just tuples (with a little extra magic), not objects of your own ("your" being, in this case, "the application developer's") design.

In general, if you're trying to programmatically build queries (particularly based on information only available at runtime), you should be using the core. If you're trying to build your application MVC-style and want database-backed objects to be the "model", you should be using the ORM.

Answer (score 13):

The SQLAlchemy-ORM is developed on top of SQLAlchemy-Core. As we can see the basic architecture of SQLAlchemy, below.

[image: Basic Architecture of SQLAlchemy]

So, if we want we can use SQLAlchemy-Core to execute the raw SQL queries after creating [engine](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/engines.html). SQLAlchemy engine object provides a set of methods to perform basic operation like connect(), execute(), etc.
for example

```py
engine = create_engine('mysql://scott:tiger@localhost/test')
connection = engine.connect()
result = connection.execute("select username from users")
for row in result:
    print("username:", row['username'])
connection.close()
```

In case you want the ORM features from SQLAlchemy, you have to use the ORM part. Where you'll be able to create the python Classes which will be treated as table and attributes of the class will be treated as columns. In addition to that, many more methods will be provided by SQLAlchemy to make things easier for Object-relational Mapping.