# query a joined table with sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have two tables one for information and the other for salary.  I have successfully joined the two tables together in my postgres CLI and in my flask app, but having problems trying to query the data in sqlalchemy.

I have tried my query on my psql CLI and works fine!

```
SELECT date, name, profession, wage FROM test2_table JOIN salary ON salary.test2_id = test2_table.id WHERE profession = 'media';
```

I suppose my main question is how could I do this in sqlalchemy?

Database class

```
class Test_db_02(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'test2_table'
    id = Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True)
    date = Column('date', String(10))
    age = Column('age', Integer)
    profession = Column('profession', String(60))
    city = Column('city', String(60))
    country = Column('country', String(60))

    def __init__(self, date, name, age, profession, city, country):
        self.date = date
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.profession = profession
        self.city = city
        self.country = country

class Salary(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'salary'
    id = Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True)
    wage = Column('wage', String(20))
    test2_id = Column('test2_id', Integer, ForeignKey('test2_table.id')
    wages = relationship("Test_db_02", backref="salary", primaryjoin="Test_db_02.id == Salary.test2_id")
```

My query in python:

```
@app.route('/reports', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def reports():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template('reports.html')
    else:
        if request.form.get("report_options) == "media_prof":
            db_entry = session.query(Test_db_02).join(Test_db_02.salary).filter(Test_db_02.profession=='media')
        media_prof = db_entry.all()
        return render_template('reports.html', media_prof=media_prof)
```

jinja template in reports.html:

```
{% if media_prof %}
    <h2>Media Freelance Reports</h2>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>NAME</th>
            <th>PROFESSION</th>
            <th>SALARY</th>
        </tr>
    {% for d in media_prof %}
        <tr>
            <th>{{ d.id }}</th>
            <th>{{ d.name }}</th>
            <th>{{ d.profession }}</th>
            <th>{{ d.salary }}</th>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Fortunately it doesn't crash my web app but instead of producing the salary for each media freelancer I get:
`[<__main__.Salary object at 0x00CF11B0>]`

I have a feeling it must be the way I queried the database in the python app or the way I am calling the variable in the jinja..

Comment: What happens if you replace `d.salary` with `d.salary.wage`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using SQLAlchemy in the ORM mode (as opposed to [core](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43300904/6203472) mode), the result of querying

```
db_entry = session.query(Test_db_02).join(Test_db_02.salary).filter(Test_db_02.profession=='media')
media_prof = db_entry.all()
```

Is a list of Test_db_02 instances, with each of the instance having a `.salary` attribute being a `Salary` instance. So its normal that when you use this in your jinja template:

```
{% for d in media_prof %}
    <tr>
        <th>{{ d.id }}</th>
        <th>{{ d.name }}</th>
        <th>{{ d.profession }}</th>
        <th>{{ d.salary }}</th>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Since `d.salary` is an actual list of `Salary` instance (due to your backref and the fact that your have a 1-to-many relationship), it means that you have access to the attribute of each salary object, e.g: `.id`, or `.wage`
e.g:

```
{% for d in media_prof %}
    <tr>
        <th>{{ d.id }}</th>
        <th>{{ d.name }}</th>
        <th>{{ d.profession }}</th>
        {% for s in media_prof.salary %}
            <th>{{ s.id }}</th>
            <th>{{ s.wage }}</th>
        {% endfor %}
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Note: consider renaming your backref "salary" into "salaries" to make that more explicit

**EDIT**:
Note that it is easier to troubleshoot things outside of the template. From a terminal, I'm able to get a proper output using the following simplified case:

```
# Load an object in the db with 2 salaries attached to it
t = Test_db_02(city='NY')
s1 = Salary(wage='crazy rich', test2_id=t)
s2 = Salary(wage='mega rich', test2_id=t)
t.salaries = [s1, s2]

session = Session()
session.add(t)
session.commit()

# query & print
session2 = Session()
for test in session2.query(Test_db_02).all():
    print(test.id, test.city)
    for salary in test.salaries:
        print(salary.id, salary.wage)
```

which prints

```
1 NY
1 crazy rich
2 mega rich
```

Comment: THANK YOU !! will try this out and get back to you! You couldn't of put it better for me to understand - the documentation was hard for me to grasp. thanks again :)

Comment: Did it work? Happy to help if you still have problem

Comment: I actually just tried this and nothing appears :( I would love to crack this code because I want to use it to create a visitor in and out system with essentially two tables...

Comment: That's weird, are you sure the item you are viewing has salaries attached to it?I've edited my answer and added a simplified example that works fine, start by printing what you want in plain python and then move it to the jinja template once its working

Comment: ok lemme test the way you have done this because i suspect I have done something wrong on my behalf!  .. ahh i have just noticed, i didn't do the bit where you make t.salaries into a list

Comment: If solution works please consider upvoting/accepting the answer ;)

Comment: I cannot thank you enough, seriously!  sorry it took a while to get back to your solution - i've been working on a few small projects (feel free to check it out https://sinclairakotoportfolio.herokuapp.com and leave a comment or review its much nicer when someone with coding experience gives me feedback so i know which areas I can improve)  Back to your solution, this has helped me far beyond what I could of hoped for - thanks again! :)