# How to access columns from joined tables in sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, orm

How do I access columns from joined tables in SQLAlchemy?

My code:

```
result = session.query(schema.Lead).join(schema.Campaign).all()
for row in result:
    print(row.id) #this works
    print(row.column_from_Campaign) #this doesn't work
```

How can I access those columns from `schema.Campaign`?
If I use `__dir__()` on row I do not see any column names from Campaign table.

Thanks for help!

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57478835/query-a-joined-table-with-sqlalchemy?rq=3) is related I think