# SQLAlchemy Error Trying To Add Foreign Key

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, foreign-keys

I have the following script which attempts to create 3 tables if they don't exist yet in my database.

I am using MySQL as database engine.

```py
    class Journal:
        USER = '******'
        PASSWORD = '******'
        HOST = '******'
        DB_NAME = 'trades_test'
    
        def __init__(self):
            self.engine = create_engine(
                f'mysql+mysqlconnector://{self.USER}:{self.PASSWORD}@{self.HOST}/{self.DB_NAME}'
            )
            self.create_openings_table()
            self.create_closings_table()
            self.create_adjustments_table()
    
        def create_openings_table(self):
            meta = MetaData(self.engine)
            self.openings = Table(
                'openings',
                meta,
                Column('trade_id',
                       INTEGER(unsigned=True),
                       primary_key=True,
                       autoincrement=True),
                Column('opened_at', DATE(), nullable=False),
                Column('underlying', VARCHAR(5), nullable=False),
                Column('underlying_price', FLOAT(2), nullable=False),
                Column('iv_rank', SMALLINT(), nullable=False),
                Column('strategy', VARCHAR(20), nullable=False),
                Column('quantity', SMALLINT(), nullable=False),
                Column('expiration_date', DATE(), nullable=False),
                Column('option_types', JSON()),
                Column('strikes', JSON(), nullable=False),
                Column('premium', FLOAT(2), nullable=False),
                Column('prob_of_profit', FLOAT(2), nullable=False),
                Column('margin', FLOAT(2), nullable=False),
                Column('notes', TEXT()))
            meta.create_all()
    
        def create_closings_table(self):
            meta = MetaData(self.engine)
            self.closings = Table(
                'closings',
                meta,
                Column('id',
                       INTEGER(unsigned=True),
                       primary_key=True,
                       autoincrement=True),
                # FOREIGN KEY - fk_closings_trade_id
                Column('trade_id', ForeignKey('openings.trade_id')),
                Column('closed_at', DATE(), nullable=False),
                Column('underlying_price', FLOAT(2), nullable=False),
                Column('iv_rank', SMALLINT(), nullable=False),
                Column('premium', FLOAT(2), nullable=False),
                Column('margin', FLOAT(2), nullable=False),
                Column('notes', TEXT()),
            )
            meta.create_all()
    
        def create_adjustments_table(self):
            meta = MetaData(self.engine)
            self.adjustments = Table(
                'adjustments',
                meta,
                Column('id',
                       INTEGER(unsigned=True),
                       primary_key=True,
                       autoincrement=True),
                # FOREIGN KEY - fk_adj_trade_id
                Column('trade_id', ForeignKey('openings.trade_id')),
                Column('adjusted_at', DATE(), nullable=False),
                Column('underlying_price', FLOAT(2), nullable=False),
                Column('iv_rank', SMALLINT(), nullable=False),
                Column('quantity', SMALLINT()),
                Column('premium', FLOAT(2)),
                Column('option_types', JSON()),
                Column('strikes', JSON()),
                Column('expiration_date', DATE()),
                Column('margin', FLOAT(2)),
                Column('notes', TEXT()),
            )
            meta.create_all()
```

This code produces this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/or/Desktop/Or/Options/journal/journal.py", line 105, in <module>
    Journal()
  File "/Users/or/Desktop/Or/Options/journal/journal.py", line 16, in __init__
    self.create_closings_table()
  File "/Users/or/Desktop/Or/Options/journal/journal.py", line 61, in create_closings_table
    meta.create_all()
  File "/Users/or/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/schema.py", line 4744, in create_all
    bind._run_ddl_visitor(
  File "/Users/or/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3008, in _run_ddl_visitor
    conn._run_ddl_visitor(visitorcallable, element, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/or/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2016, in _run_ddl_visitor
    visitorcallable(self.dialect, self, **kwargs).traverse_single(element)
  File "/Users/or/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/visitors.py", line 483, in traverse_single
    return meth(obj, **kw)
  File "/Users/or/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/ddl.py", line 822, in visit_metadata
    collection = sort_tables_and_constraints(
  File "/Users/or/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/ddl.py", line 1286, in sort_tables_and_constraints
    dependent_on = fkc.referred_table
  File "/Users/or/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/schema.py", line 3671, in referred_table
    return self.elements[0].column.table
  File "/Users/or/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 1093, in __get__
    obj.__dict__[self.__name__] = result = self.fget(obj)
  File "/Users/or/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/schema.py", line 2376, in column
    raise exc.NoReferencedTableError(
sqlalchemy.exc.NoReferencedTableError: Foreign key associated with column 'closings.trade_id' could not find table 'openings' with which to generate a foreign key to target column 'trade_id'
```

I would like the primary key of the first table (trade_id) to serve as a foreign key in the other two tables.

I've also seen other ways of constructing the tables, mainly combined with Flask, that create subclasses of a Model class and fill out the details of the table there, what would be the more correct way to construct a small database application like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue with the primary key happens because the `MetaData` object is a storage object for a series of tables. When defining a foreign key it looks into the `MetaData` object for the relevant table to map to. As you are redefining the `MetaData` object in the different create functions they are all stored in a different `MetaData` object. Due to this the foreign key cannot be looked up during the creation of the second table with a relation to the first table.

The solution is to define the `MetaData` object once and refer each `Table` object to this `MetaData` object.

See [Working with Database Metadata](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/tutorial/metadata.html#working-with-database-metadata) for more information about this.

Also you don't have to call `create_all` in each create function but it can be called once at the end of `__init__`.

Regarding your last question about the different methods is that your method is mainly SQLAlchemy Core. When using subclasses of `Base` you are getting into SQLAlchemy ORM. Here the differences are explained a little bit more: [What is the difference between SQLAlchemy Core and ORM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43300886/what-is-the-difference-between-sqlalchemy-core-and-orm)

Comment: I have put them all under one function and it works perfect, thank you for the great answer.