# SQLAlchemy error relation "table_name" does not exist

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

Im trying to build tables with many-to-many relationship from my models file, but I'm getting error:
[relation "Cities" does not exist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QRdSe.png)

I think that there is an issue with my many-to-many relationship because one-to-many worked fine.

Models.py file:

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, String, Integer, Table
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import backref, relationship
from sqlalchemy.sql.schema import ForeignKey

base = declarative_base()

cities_sensors = Table('cities_sensors', base.metadata,
                       Column('cities_id', ForeignKey('Cities.id')),
                       Column('sensors_id', ForeignKey('Sensors.id'))
                       )


class Cities(base):
    __tablename__ = 'Cities'
    id = Column(Integer, unique=True, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    sensors = relationship(
        'Sensors', secondary=cities_sensors)


class Sensors(base):
    __tablename__ = 'Sensors'
    id = Column(Integer, unique=True, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    unit = Column(String)
```

db_init.py file:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, session
from sqlalchemy.orm.session import Session
from models import Cities, Sensors
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

db_string = "postgresql://postgres:1234@localhost:5438"

db = create_engine(db_string)
base = declarative_base()

Session = sessionmaker(db)
session = Session()

base.metadata.create_all(db)

czestochowa_city = Cities(name="Czestochowa")

myszkow_city = Cities(name="Myszkow")

krzepice_city = Cities(name="Krzepice")


temperature_sensor = Sensors(name="temperature",
                             unit="Celsius")

humidity_sensor = Sensors(name="humidity",
                          unit="precentage")

pollution_sensor = Sensors(name="pollution",
                           unit="PM2.5")

session.add(czestochowa_city)
session.add(myszkow_city)
session.add(krzepice_city)
session.add(temperature_sensor)
session.add(humidity_sensor)
session.add(pollution_sensor)


session.commit()
```

Do you guys see what I'm doing here wrong?

Comment: Your code seems ok, but can you check in some tool like `psql` at the command line or `pgadminIII` if the tables were actually created?

Comment: I checked it with pgAdmin, unfortunately tables were not created.

Comment: Debugging idea: see if the `db_string` would work to access the database just using `psycopg2` since it's less boilerplate.

Comment: You are redefining `base` in db_init.py. As `base` is the storage object redefining it doesn't work as this doesn't contain any tables. Remove `base = declarative_base()` from db_init.py and import it from models: `from models import Cities, Sensors, base`

Comment: @rfkortekaas Thank you, that was the issue :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQLAlchemy Error Trying To Add Foreign Key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68183161/sqlalchemy-error-trying-to-add-foreign-key)