# SQLAlchemy MetaData.reflect() vs. automap_base.prepare()

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

It seems to me that `MetaData.reflect()` and `sqlalchemy.ext.automap.prepare()` tables should be able to be used interchangeably for many use cases, but they can't be.

The `metadata.tables['mytable']` into `conn.execute(select(...))` returns a `sqlalchemy.engine.cursor.CursorResult` and your iterator gets the columns directly (eg `x.columnA`).

But `automap_base().classes.mytable` into the same `conn.execute(select(...))` returns a `sqlalchemy.engine.result.ChunkedIteratorResult`  and you need `x.mytable.columnA` to get at the column.

The [sqlalchemy.engine.Result()](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.Result) documention says as much:

> New in version 1.4: The Result object provides a completely updated
> usage model and calling facade for SQLAlchemy Core and SQLAlchemy ORM.
> In Core, it forms the basis of the CursorResult object which replaces
> the previous ResultProxy interface. When using the ORM, a higher level
> object called ChunkedIteratorResult is normally used.

**Can I generically convert one to the other?**  That is, some wrapper that works for every table without needing the table name?

**What's the best futureproof way to do this?**  I want my code to be forward-looking to sqlalchemy 2.0. Does that mean I should move away from either `automap` or `MetaData`?

sqlalchemy 1.4.35

Answer (score 1):

[This is the difference between the Core and the ORM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43300886/what-is-the-difference-between-sqlalchemy-core-and-orm).

> [select() from a Table vs. ORM class](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/tutorial/data_select.html#the-select-sql-expression-construct)
>
> While the SQL generated in these examples looks the same whether we
> invoke select(user_table) or select(User), in the more general case
> they do not necessarily render the same thing, as an ORM-mapped class
> may be mapped to other kinds of “selectables” besides tables. The
> select() that’s against an ORM entity also indicates that ORM-mapped
> instances should be returned in a result, which is not the case when
> SELECTing from a Table object.

Don't hesitate to use the ORM. It's higher level, pythonic, cool, and automap is ORM.