# Apache Airflow - (mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError) 2003 - Can't connect to MySQL server on '35.188.119.171:3306' (110 Connection timed out)

Tags: sqlalchemy, google-cloud-sql, mysql-connector, airflow-webserver, mysql-error-2003

I am trying to insert .csv files located into gcp buckets into my Mysql database which is a cloud SQL instance I have set up in google cloud platform.
It runs flawlessly on my local machine (When I run the notebook I have created) but when I try to run it on Apache Airflow, I got these errors from the logs:

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/operators/python.py", line 181, in execute
    return_value = self.execute_callable()
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/operators/python.py", line 198, in execute_callable
    return self.python_callable(*self.op_args, **self.op_kwargs)
  File "/home/airflow/gcs/dags/workflow_test2.py", line 482, in split_data_to_MySql_db
    conn = engine.connect()
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3325, in connect
    return self._connection_cls(self, close_with_result=close_with_result)
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 96, in __init__
    else engine.raw_connection()
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3404, in raw_connection
    return self._wrap_pool_connect(self.pool.connect, _connection)
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3374, in _wrap_pool_connect
    Connection._handle_dbapi_exception_noconnection(
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2208, in _handle_dbapi_exception_noconnection
    util.raise_(
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 211, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3371, in _wrap_pool_connect
    return fn()
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 327, in connect
    return _ConnectionFairy._checkout(self)
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 894, in _checkout
    fairy = _ConnectionRecord.checkout(pool)
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 493, in checkout
    rec = pool._do_get()
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py", line 146, in _do_get
    self._dec_overflow()
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 70, in __exit__
    compat.raise_(
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 211, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py", line 143, in _do_get
    return self._create_connection()
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 273, in _create_connection
    return _ConnectionRecord(self)
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 388, in __init__
    self.__connect()
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 691, in __connect
    pool.logger.debug("Error on connect(): %s", e)
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 70, in __exit__
    compat.raise_(
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 211, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 686, in __connect
    self.dbapi_connection = connection = pool._invoke_creator(self)
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/create.py", line 574, in connect
    return dialect.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 598, in connect
    return self.dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mysql/connector/pooling.py", line 323, in connect
    return MySQLConnection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 173, in __init__
    self.connect(**kwargs)
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mysql/connector/abstracts.py", line 1363, in connect
    self._open_connection()
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 353, in _open_connection
    self._socket.open_connection()
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mysql/connector/network.py", line 760, in open_connection
    raise InterfaceError(
sqlalchemy.exc.InterfaceError: (mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError) 2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on '35.188.119.171:3306' (110 Connection timed out)
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/rvf5)
[2024-01-17, 09:32:47 CET] {taskinstance.py:1346} INFO - Marking task as FAILED. dag_id=poke_dag, task_id=split_data_to_MySql_db_task, execution_date=20240117T081250, start_date=20240117T083032, end_date=20240117T083247
[2024-01-17, 09:32:47 CET] {standard_task_runner.py:104} ERROR - Failed to execute job 502 for task split_data_to_MySql_db_task ((mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError) 2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on '35.188.119.171:3306' (110 Connection timed out)
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/rvf5); 908)
[2024-01-17, 09:32:47 CET] {local_task_job_runner.py:225} INFO - Task exited with return code 1
[2024-01-17, 09:32:47 CET] {taskinstance.py:2656} INFO - 0 downstream tasks scheduled from follow-on schedule check
```

I know that the connection cannot be established between my db and airflow but I can't understand why.
More over here is my code to export the data from the .csv files:

```py
def split_data_to_MySql_db():

    from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Column, Integer, String, Float, DateTime, ForeignKey,text
    from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
    from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker


     # Récupération de ebay_sales_data
    object_name = 'split_data/ebay_sales_data.csv'
    bucket = client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
    blob = bucket.blob(object_name)
    content = blob.download_as_text()
    ebay_sales_data_df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(content)) 

     # Récupération de ebay_seller_data
    object_name = 'split_data/ebay_seller_data.csv'
    bucket = client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
    blob = bucket.blob(object_name)
    content = blob.download_as_text()
    ebay_seller_df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(content))  

     # Récupération de pokemon_card_data
    object_name = 'split_data/pokemon_card_data.csv'
    bucket = client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
    blob = bucket.blob(object_name)
    content = blob.download_as_text()
    pokemon_card_df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(content)) 

    # Déclaration des paramètres nécessaires pour la connexion à la base de données
    DB_USER = '<USERNAME>'
    DB_PASSWORD = '<PASSWORD>'
    DB_HOST = '<HOST>'
    DB_PORT = '<PORT>'
    DB_NAME = '<DATABASE>'

    # Créez une connexion à la base de données MySQL
    engine = create_engine(f'mysql+mysqlconnector://{DB_USER}:{DB_PASSWORD}@{DB_HOST}:{DB_PORT}/{DB_NAME}', echo=True) 

    # Créez une session pour insérer les données
    Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
    session = Session()

    # Obtenez une connexion de l'engine
    conn = engine.connect()

    # Désactivez temporairement la vérification des clés étrangères
    conn.execute(text('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;'))

    # Insérez les données des DataFrames dans la base de données
    ebay_seller_df.to_sql('ebay_seller', con=engine, if_exists='append', index=False)
    pokemon_card_df.to_sql('pokemon_card', con=engine, if_exists='append', index=False)
    ebay_sales_data_df.to_sql('ebay_sales_data', con=engine, if_exists='append', index=False)


    # Réactivez la vérification des clés étrangères
    conn.execute(text('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;'))

    # Fermez la session et la connexion à la base de données
    session.close()
    conn.close()
    engine.dispose()
```

N.B. : I am using this function in my DAGs task as a PythonOperator and not a sqloperator

Thank you for your help !

Because my python codes is running in the cloud and on the airflow web server, I wanted to allow connections to the Cloud SQL for the airflow web server ip but I cannot find it. It might not be the good solutions tho.

Comment: Hi, if the IP and the user/passwords are real, please change them to hidden or artificial values.

Comment: What about application of CloudSQLImportInstanceOperator "Imports data into a Cloud SQL instance from a SQL dump or CSV file in Cloud Storage" https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/stable/operators/cloud/cloud_sql.html#cloudsqlexecutequeryoperator. In my opinion ready, out of the box solutions are better than custom ones.

Comment: Are you using the Composer-Airflow or the standalone Airflow, setup somewhere (locally, in the Cloud)?

Comment: My recommendation is to use the [Cloud SQL Python Connector](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-python-connector). You do not need to whitelist IP addresses and the connections are encrypted. Very easy to modify your code to implement the connector.

Comment: Editing your post does not remove your secrets. Users can see edit revisions. I recommend that you immediately change the password.

Comment: I am using Composer-airflow in the cloud. I will try with the Cloud SQL Python Connector ; ) Thnak you for your answers

Comment: This is a personal project haha and yea my bad for leaking those information

Answer (score 1):

As one of the comments above mentions, you can leverage the [Cloud SQL Python Connector](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-python-connector) package to connect without needing to allowlist IP addresses and for default secure connections.

Basic usage looks as follows:

```py
from google.cloud.sql.connector import Connector
import sqlalchemy

# initialize Connector object
connector = Connector()

# function to return the database connection
def getconn():
    conn = connector.connect(
        "project:region:instance",
        "pymysql",
        user="my-user",
        password="my-password",
        db="my-db-name"
    )
    return conn

# create connection pool
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(
    "mysql+pymysql://",
    creator=getconn,
)

connector.close()
```

One thing I want to point out about your above code (besides needing to change your secrets as you have leaked them) is that SQLAlchemy has two different APIs, [SQLAlchemy Core](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/) and [SQLAlchemy ORM](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/) which you seem to be using both. You rarely ever want to use both APIs and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43300886/what-is-the-difference-between-sqlalchemy-core-and-orm) does a good job explaining the difference between the two. It looks as though you just want a simple query builder for your use-case so you can most likely remove all the `Session` ORM code from your code.

Comment: Alroight thank you so much I will try with the cliud SQL operator and see for those APIs differences ;)

Comment: I am getting this error when trying to run your code from google.cloud.sql.connector import Connector
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google.cloud.sql'

Comment: @JeanGuinvarch did you pip install the package as explained in the documentation https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-python-connector?tab=readme-ov-file#installation

Comment: Yes it is fine now but I have another problem...

Comment: I posted my problem in the answer section